# Why aren't the variables storing?

Tags: php

Okay, as you can see in the code I'm trying to add the total up.. I have used a variable outside a while() before, but not this way. So if someone could point me in the right direction? I know what I need to make the form work, that's not the problem. My formatting is bad, but that's not the problem either so please no comments on it.

```
<?php
require 'core/config.php';
?>
<form onsubmit="sendToServer();">
CPU <select id="proc">
<?php
$cpuPrice = "";
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM partslist WHERE Category = 'CPU'");
while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $cpuPrice .= $row['ProductPrice'];
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ProductName'].'">'.$row['ProductName'].' - '.$row['ProductPrice'].'</option>'; 
}
?>
</select><br>

RAM <select id="proc1">
<?php
$ramPrice = "";
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM partslist WHERE Category = 'RAM'");
while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $ramPrice .= $row['ProductPrice'];
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ProductName'].'">'.$row['ProductName'].' - '.$row['ProductPrice'].'</option>'; 
}
?>
</select><br>

GPU <select id="proc2">
<?php
$gpuPrice = "";
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM partslist WHERE Category = 'GPU'");
while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $gpuPrice .= $row['ProductPrice'];
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ProductName'].'">'.$row['ProductName'].' - '.$row['ProductPrice'].'</option>'; 
}
?>
</select><br>

HDD <select id="proc3">
<?php
$hddPrice = "";
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM partslist WHERE Category = 'HDD'");
while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $hddPrice .= $row['ProductPrice'];
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ProductName'].'">'.$row['ProductName'].' - '.$row['ProductPrice'].'</option>'; 
}
?>
</select><br>

SSD <select id="proc4">
<?php
$ssdPrice = "";
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM partslist WHERE Category = 'SSD'");
while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $ssdPrice .= $row['ProductPrice'];
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ProductName'].'">'.$row['ProductName'].' - '.$row['ProductPrice'].'</option>'; 
}

$total = $cpuPrice + $ramPrice + $gpuPrice + $hddPrice + $ssdPrice;
?>
</select><br><br>

<button type="submit">Build</button>
</form>
<div style="border:1px;border-color:black;">Total: $<?php echo $total; ?></div>
```

Edit - more in depth..
What I need is to display the total, but it's empty..

Comment: U have to use the `+` operator to calculate with integers, floats,... `.` is used to contenate strings

Comment: `.` operator is used to concatenate variables values. If you want to sum, use the `+` operator.

Comment: @Shad you dont see what the guys are pointing out ? you need `$cpuPrice += $row['ProductPrice'];`

Comment: @meda, I did the above and the total still comes out as 0?

Comment: define the prices as 0 instead of "" too

Comment: convert it to integers `$cpuPrice += (int)$row['ProductPrice'];` @shad

Comment: It seems the values in the variables inside the loop aren't getting stored and it's using the variables outside the loop.

Comment: Honestly If I were you I would do the calculation in the query I would mess with all these loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the math in the query itself, for example:

```
CPU <select id="proc">
<?php
$cpuPrice = 0;
$query = $con->query("SELECT *, (SUM(ProductPrice)) as CpuPrice FROM partslist WHERE Category = 'CPU'");
while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $cpuPrice = $row['CpuPrice '];
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ProductName'].'">'.$row['ProductName'].' - '.$row['ProductPrice'].'</option>'; 
}
echo 'cpuPrice'.$cpuPrice;
?>
</select><br>
```